# Portainer Docker Volumes problem: Duplicate mount point

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

I use the latest Portainer Version 2.14. BE

Docker Compose yml (relevant part) you can see below.

The shared-folder worked at first Stack > Update the Stack, Pull latest images worked once fine and the shared-folders also work fine after that.

But as soon I want now to recreate the web or engine container, pulling the newest image, I get:"Duplicate mount point: /app/engine/shared-folder". The same happens when updating Stack with the latest images. After this error portainer creates a web-old or engine-old container with the old version, the new version is not created.

A workaround is, that before recreating/pull the latest web or engine container, to delete via Portainer the shared-folder volume, and after that recreate.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: company/be:latest
    volumes:
      - ./log:/app/log
      - .:/go/src/app
      - ./empty:/go/src/app/docker
      - shared-folder:/app/engine/shared-folder
    ports:
      - 3010:3010
  engine:
    container_name: engine
    image: company/engine:latest
    volumes:
      - ./log:/app/log
      - .:/go/src/app
      - ./empty:/go/src/app/docker
      - shared-folder:/app/engine/shared-folder

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: production_default

volumes:
  shared-folder:
  cache:
    driver: local
```